# finding $n$-th term from sum of $n$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of the first n terms of a series is $(4n+5)^2$ and I need to find the nth term. This is all the information given - it doesn't say if it is a geometric series or arithmetic and I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: $T_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is far simpler than it looks. Let's write

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i = (4n + 5)^2\ .$$

where $a_i$ are the terms of the series. You want to find $a_n$, and one way to get that would be to sum all the numbers in the series up to $a_n$ and subtract all the numbers in the series up to $a_{n-1}$.

So, we have

$$ a_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i - \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} a_i\ .$$

Luckily we already have a formula for calculating the sum of elements up to any $n$! You should be able to work the rest out from here.

Incidentally, once you get the answer you'll realise the series is arithmetic.